# cv::cvtColor gets wrong size image

Tags: c++, opencv, yuv

I am using the following code to convert a RGB format image to a YUVI420 format image, but the result i420Mat is wrong in color and size.

```
cv::cvtColor(rgbMat, i420Mat, CV_RGB2YUV_I420);
```

Source rgbMat(RGB Format) : cols: 480, rows: 640;

Corresponding CIImage:

[image]

Destination i420Mat(YUVI420 Format): cols: 480, rows: 960;

Corresponding CIImage:

[image]

Ideally, they should keep the same size, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it shouldn't keep the same size, since YUV_I420 is planar. And please note that input image was 3-channel, but output image is 1-channel.

Image has bigger size, because top part of image (640*480) represents Y' plane (luma), and bottom part represent U and V components correspondingly. So all color planes are represented on one single-channel image, so it has a bigger size. See image from wikipedia:

[image]

Y' plane is quite the same as grayscale image.

**Why do we see four images in the bottom?**

Top two images corresponds to U plane. Left image is for even rows, right is for odd rows. The same is for V plane in the bottom.

For additional information please read nice article in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV), and [fourcc.org](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#IYUV).